# Querying from two already joined tables

Tags: php, postgresql, join

I do hope I can explain my case by giving you this example. I tried my best to illustrate the problem. I have two tables, **Entry** and **Storage**. Joined together by **Product** table, but that won't be a concern. So here goes:

**Entry**

[image]

**Storage**

[image]

**The relation :**

1) **storages** are identified by the product_id. **multiple storages can exist** having the **same product_id** .

**Join query:**

```
select 
   e.id,
   e.group_id,
   e.product_id,
   e.name,
   s.volume  
from 
   entry e,
   storage s
where
   e.group_id = '840' and
   s.product_id = e.product_id
```

**Output table :**

[image]

**Problem :**

The output table above is fine, this is the joined structure I need. However I still need to perform queries from these table, there are 5 cases I need to solve :

- Find All **entries** with **only one storage, positive volume**. (green)
- Find All **entries** with **multiple storage, positive volume**. (yellow)
- Find All **entries** with **only one storage, zero volume**. (red)
- Find All **entries** with **multiple storage records but zero volume**. (not there)
- Find All **entries** with **non existent storage**. (not there)

Yes, it can happen that the storage does not exist. I'm using Postgresql, and PHP, I can do this programatically once I have the joined table, but sql queries are cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: how if it have **one storage** and **zero volume** or **multiple storage** and **zero volume**, what color it has to be?

Comment: good point.. maybe i'll have to add that to the list of cases as well? I don't know yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to turn the "joined table" into a view:

```
CREATE VIEW entry_products AS
  SELECT e.id, e.group_id, e.product_id, e.name, s.volume  
  FROM entry e
  LEFT JOIN storage s ON s.product_id = e.product_id;
```

You can now query against the view:

Entries with a single storage, positive volume:

```
SELECT id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
FROM entry_products
WHERE volume > 0
GROUP BY id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

Entries with a multiple storage, positive volume:

```
SELECT id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
FROM entry_products
WHERE volume > 0
GROUP BY id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Entries with a single storage, zero volume:

```
SELECT id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
FROM entry_products
WHERE volume = 0
GROUP BY id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

Entries with a multiple storage, zero volume:

```
SELECT id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
FROM entry_products
WHERE volume = 0
GROUP BY id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

No storage:

```
SELECT *
FROM entry_products
WHERE volume IS NULL;
```

Note that I left the `e.group_id = 840` filter out of the view and the queries. If you only ever use this query with group_id = 840, then you can put it back into the view; if you use different group_id values at different times, then add the corresponding `WHERE` clause to each of the queries on the view.

Note that you can wrap each of the above queries in a separate view to make the querying even easier:

```
-- Single storage, positive volume
CREATE VIEW ep_one_pos AS
  SELECT id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
  FROM entry_products
  WHERE volume > 0
  GROUP BY id, group_id, product_id, name, volume
  HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

And then you can simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM ep_one_pos
WHERE group_id = 840;
```

Comment: @ColourDalnet: I am happy to see from your answer that you have already learned from me! {;-P

Comment: i like the view concept.. but doesn't it require me to update this always?

Comment: @muffin: The whole idea behind the view is that it pulls the data from the underlying tables every time you query the view. So whenever you use the view, you get the up-to-date information from the tables. In building such hierarchies (you can create a view from a view, and so on) and when using sub-queries, you should think of the result as a new set of data in tabular format. PostgreSQL calls this a "relation".

Comment: ohw right , i was thinking about materialized view instead of regular view. I'll accept this as an answer thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just showing how to do sub-select for your problem, I will update the answer after you update the question :

```
select *, (case when (x.volume = 0) then 'RED' else 'OTHER' end) as color
    select 
       e.id as id,
       e.group_id as group_id,
       e.product_id as product_id,
       e.name as name,
       s.volume as volume 
    from 
       entry e full outer join storage s
    on
       s.product_id = e.product_id
    where
       e.group_id = '840'
) as x
```

--EDITED--

1. Find All entries with only one storage, positive volume. (green)

   ```
   select 
      e.id,
      e.group_id,
      e.product_id,
      e.name,
      s.volume
   from 
      entry e full outer join storage s
   on
      s.product_id = e.product_id
   where
      e.group_id = '840' and s.volume > 0
   group by e.id, e.group_id, e.product_id, e.name, s.volume
   having count(*) = 1
   ```
2. Find All entries with multiple storage, positive volume. (yellow)

   ```
   select 
      e.id,
      e.group_id,
      e.product_id,
      e.name,
      s.volume
   from 
      entry e full outer join storage s
   on
      s.product_id = e.product_id
   where
      e.group_id = '840' and s.volume > 0
   group by e.id, e.group_id, e.product_id, e.name, s.volume
   having count(*) > 1
   ```
3. Find All entries with only one storage, zero volume. (red)

   ```
   select 
      e.id,
      e.group_id,
      e.product_id,
      e.name,
      s.volume
   from 
      entry e full outer join storage s
   on
      s.product_id = e.product_id
   where
      e.group_id = '840' and s.volume = 0
   group by e.id, e.group_id, e.product_id, e.name, s.volume
   having count(*) = 1
   ```
4. Find All entries with multiple storage records but zero volume. (not there)

   ```
   select 
      e.id,
      e.group_id,
      e.product_id,
      e.name,
      s.volume
   from 
      entry e full outer join storage s
   on
      s.product_id = e.product_id
   where
      e.group_id = '840' and s.volume = 0
   group by e.id, e.group_id, e.product_id, e.name, s.volume
   having count(*) > 1
   ```
5. Find All entries with non existent storage. (not there)

   `select * from entry where product_id not in (select product_id from storage)`

Comment: i don't actually have to "color" it.. i just need a query for each of these 5 cases. basically i need  5 select statements for these 5 cases. thanks!

Comment: do you mean just make the quries separately into 5 query?

Comment: yeah. 1 query for each of the cases.

Comment: ok, I will update it one by one, just comment if found any errors.

Comment: Done, check it all ;)

Comment: This solves the problem but the view concept was more clever.. i'll upvote this. Thank you!